# How to add the Menu in VSIX project from code behind instead for using it from .vsct file?

Tags: c#, vsix

In VSIX how to add the Menu from code behind using c# instead for using it from .vsct file?

```
<Menu guid="guidMenuPackageCmdSet" id="DynamicMenu" priority="0x700" type="Menu">
   <Parent guid="guidcMenuPackageCmdSet" id="MenuGroup"/>
      <Strings>
         <ButtonText>DynamicMenu</ButtonText>
       </Strings>
</Menu>
```

I have added the commands button dynamically using below codes, but I don't know how to add the Menu.

```
private static readonly List<OleMenuCommand> _commands = new List<OleMenuCommand>();

protected override void BeforeQueryStatus(EventArgs e){

if (_commands.Any()){
return;
}

IEnumerable<MenuItem> subMenuItem_1 = MenuItemStore.SubMenuItem_1.Value;
OleMenuCommandService mcs = Package.GetService<IMenuCommandService, OleMenuCommandService>();

foreach (MenuItem item in subMenuItem_1){
CommandID cmdId = new CommandID(CommandSet, DynamicSubMenuCommandId1 + j++);
OleMenuCommand command = new OleMenuCommand(Execute, cmdId);
SetupCommand(command, item);
mcs.AddCommand(command);
}

}



private void SetupCommand(OleMenuCommand command, MenuItem menuItem){
command.Enabled = command.Visible = true;
command.Text = menuItem.Name;
command.Checked = menuItem.IsActive;
_commands.Add(command);
}
```